# How to get total devices count in a group in a nested array recursively?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
const array= [
  {
    "groupId": "group1",
    "devices": ["5","6"],
    "children": [
      {
        "groupId": "group11",
        "devices": ["1","2","3","4"],
        "children": [
          {
            "groupId": "group111",
            "devices": ["7","8","9","0"],
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "groupId": "group112",
            "devices": ["7","8","9","0"],
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "groupId": "group12",
        "devices": ["1","2","3","4"],
        "children": [
          {
            "groupId": "group121",
            "devices": ["7","8","9","0"],
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is an array which could have n number of children nested.
The expected outcome with a recursive typescript function should return the count of all devices under a group.

For example:

```
group1 : 22
group11 : 12
group11 : 8
group121 : 4
```

I have created a method which would generate the count and add to the array which is not generating the desired results.

```
this.getdevicesCount(this.array, 0);


/**
     * Recursive method to find Number of devices in a group
     */
    getdevicesCount(array: any[], devcount: number) {
        array.forEach((group) => {
            devcount = devcount + group.devices.length;
            if(group.children.length) {
                this.getdevicesCount(group.children, devcount);
            }
            group.count = devcount;
            devcount = 0;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that in JS/TS, arguments are passed by value. In particular, your 2nd parameter `devcount` is a primitive type (`number`), so there is no way modifying its value within the body of `this.getdevicesCount` function could have the side effect of modifying the argument value outside.

Instead of trying to modify the argument value, you could just `return` it:

```
getdevicesCount(array: any[]) {
  const total = 0;
  array.forEach((group) => {
    group.count =
      group.devices.length
      + this.getdevicesCount(group.children);
    total += group.count;
  });
  return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function only computes a value for a single key, if you want all counts in an object, you'll need a function that returns the count and populates the object at the same time, for example:

```js
function count(arr) {
    let res = {}

    function cnt(a) {
        res[a.groupId] = a.devices?.length ?? 0
        for (let c of (a.children ?? []))
            res[a.groupId] += cnt(c)
        return res[a.groupId]
    }

    for (let a of arr)
        cnt(a)

    return res

}

//

const array= [
    {
        "groupId": "group1",
        "devices": ["5","6"],
        "children": [
            {
                "groupId": "group11",
                "devices": ["1","2","3","4"],
                "children": [
                    {
                        "groupId": "group111",
                        "devices": ["7","8","9","0"],
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "groupId": "group112",
                        "devices": ["7","8","9","0"],
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "groupId": "group12",
                "devices": ["1","2","3","4"],
                "children": [
                    {
                        "groupId": "group121",
                        "devices": ["7","8","9","0"],
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

//

console.log(count(array))
```